# absolute div on overflow hiding

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to disply the absolute div that overflows from the container.

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kongaraju/bhYUa/2/)

Here are my requirements:

1. fixed div that overflows content.
2. overflow-y should be auto to scroll but not  overflow-y
3. absolute div should be displayed.
4. page should not be scroll the only fixed position div should be scroll

And here are the problems I am having:

1. on putting overflow property for panel the absolute div is hiding.
2. and on remove of overflow property the panel not scrolling.

css

```
                    #panel {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0px;
                right: 20%;
                bottom: 0px;
                background: snow;
            }
            .contact {
                background: skyblue;
                position: relative;
                height:50px;
            }
            .std {
                width: 80px;
            }
            .vtl {
                position: absolute;
                background: red;
                display: none;
                left:-153px;
                margin-top:-35px;
                width: 150px;
                height: 50px;
            }
            .vtl:after {
                content: ' ';
                height: 0;
                position: absolute;
                width: 0;
                border: 10px solid transparent;
                border-left-color: red;
                left: 100%;
                top: 10px;
            }
            .contact:hover .vtl {
                display: block;
            }
```

html

```
<div id="panel">
            <div class="contact">
                <div class="std">
                    Hover me!
                </div>
                <div class="vtl">
                    tools
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <div class="std">
                    Hover me!
                </div>
                <div class="vtl">
                    tools
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <div class="std">
                    Hover me!
                </div>
                <div class="vtl">
                    tools
                </div>
            </div>


                    ......

                </div>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pZQrA/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `<div class="std">` is contained within the `<div id="panel">` which has a fixed position, you will need to expand the width of `#panel` in order to display the content within the `<div class="std">`. For example:

HTML

```
<div id="panel">
  <div class="contact">
    <div class="std">
     Hover me!
    </div>
    <div class="vtl">
     tools
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#panel {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 20%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: snow;
  width:260px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.contact {
  background: skyblue;
  position: relative;
  height:50px;
}
.std {
  width: 80px;
  float:right;
}
.vtl {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  display: none;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:-10px;   
  height: 50px;
}
.vtl:after {
  content: ' ';
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left-color: red;
  left: 100%;
  top: 10px;
}
.contact:hover .vtl {
  display: block;
}​
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pZQrA/

Comment: I must need a fixed panel as per my context, it only support my layout

Comment: hmm it is not useful for me. i trying to change html and height of the  panel

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean? What exactly isn't useful?

Comment: position absolute is scrolling the page i dont want that

Comment: @rameshbabu I posted the wrong link. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/pZQrA/ I updated my answer with the correct link too.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. For id panel, put absolute position.

```
#panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            right: 20%;
            bottom: 0px;
            background: snow;

        }
```

Comment: it should nt help me i was already specified i must need it fixed

Comment: chrome only i dont need other browser support

Comment: I looked up a little about fixed position..."fixed boxes do not move when the document is scrolled"...source: "http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning"

Comment: thats what i want and inside divs are scrollable so i am trying to make that inside div should be scrollable